# How to convert Objects in an array to array of items after mongoose aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, destructuring

I ran the following Query in mongoose and it is successful query

```
        const recmessages = await messages.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            conversationId: {
              $in: mapedId
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            time: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$conversationId",
            messages: {
              $push: "$$ROOT"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            messages: {
              $slice: [
                "$messages",
                5
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ])
```

The returned data however has the following form. If I use {$unwind:$messages}, the returned messages array is no longer an object but the messages is no longer an array.

```
[ { _id: 5e7bb66d99aa010ca9bfeed9,
messages: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },

{ _id: 5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12,
messages: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

my question how can I end up with the same query result, with the messages field a destructed array of items instead of objects

Comment: Hi there! The question above is not clear to me, you asked how you can end up with the same result, what result? Can you please provide a clearer explanation on what exactly the problem is and what a possible solution would achieve?

Comment: sure I will edit the question

Comment: @Tunmee if you look at the results of my query the messages field is an array of objects. I want the messages field a destructured array of items instead of object. For example, messages:[{sender:one ,reciever:two},{sender:three, reciever:four}]

Comment: I think I get what the problem is now. Can you please share the schema of the messages entity or a sample messages document?

Comment: @Ahmed : It's still a bit confusing, Can you post your actual collections sample doc & req o/p it would be easy that way..